# "Unrecognized field" Jackson

Tags: java, json, deserialization, jackson

I'm trying to deserialise a JSON object from this JSON code:

```
{ 
    "bg" : { 
        "fileName" : "data/gui/mainMenuBg.jpg"
    },
    "startGameBtn" : { 
        "text" : "Start Game",
        "innerWidth" : 100,
        "innerHeight" : 50
    }
}
```

The object I'm deserialising simply looks like this:

```
public class MainMenu extends BasicTWLGameState {
    private StateBasedGame app;

    @JsonProperty private Image bg;
    @JsonProperty private Button startGameBtn;
    // [...]
}
```

I created a mix-in for the base class of the `Button` class:

```
public abstract class WidgetMixIn {
    // Not sure why I have to ignore only this when there are other setters that it should complain about...
    @JsonIgnore public abstract boolean setBorderSize(Border border);

    @JsonProperty("innerWidth") public abstract int getInnerWidth();
    @JsonProperty("innerHeight") public abstract int getInnerHeight();

    public abstract void setInnerSize(
            @JsonProperty("innerWidth") int width,
            @JsonProperty("innerHeight") int height);
}
```

The mix-in for the `Button` class itself:

```
public class ButtonMixIn {
    @JsonProperty public String text;
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
ERROR:Unrecognized field "innerWidth" (Class de.matthiasmann.twl.Button), not marked as ignorable
    at [Source: data\gui\mainMenu.json; line: 7, column: 27] (through reference chain: state.MainMenu["startGameBtn"]->de.matthiasmann.twl.Button["innerWidth"])
```

Why can it not find the `innerWidth` property defined in the `Widget` mix-in?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

ButtonMixIn class does not have a innerHeight and innerWidth JsonProperty annotation.

If ButtonMixIn class was meant to extend from your defined abstract button class, then you are missing the ButtonMixIn extends WidgetMixIn line.

Comment: I extended it, but I still get the same error:
`public abstract class ButtonMixIn extends WidgetMixIn {
    @JsonProperty public String text;
}`

Comment: My guess then is you are missing accessors and mutators for your variables, and also could you make the parent variables protected or private for encapsulation?

Comment: The accessors and mutators are there:

Button: http://pastebin.com/3raLuwNd
TextWidget: http://pastebin.com/pD3nWci8
Widget: http://pastebin.com/LL0m0AAT

What do you mean by the parent variables?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your "setInnerSize()" -- Java bean property setters only allow setting one property at a time; multiple properties can only be used with annotated constructors.
So you need to split this into two separate setters.

For what it is worth, there is a feature enhacement request to let Jackson use multi-argument setters, but current versions do not support that yet.

Comment: I'd have to be able to split the setters in the Widget class though, right? Unfortunately I don't have access to that as it's a third party class.

Comment: Correct, that is problematic. Custom deserializer may then be the way to go, unfortunately.